# NodeJS and Node-webkit file upload with progress

Tags: node.js, file-upload, stream, progress-bar, node-webkit

I am creating a desktop app using node-webkit.
The app scans a directory and uploads all the files from that directory to my server.

I have the upload working ok(i couldn't get streaming to work on the server side so just using POST).

Here is the code at the moment, I am using the request library:

```
var r = request.post("http://myserver.com/upload/");
var upload = fs.createReadStream('path/to/my/file.txt')

var form = r.form();
form.append('new_file', upload);


upload.on("data", function (chunk) {
   upload_progress += chunk.length
})

upload.on("end", function (res) {
    //upload finished

})
```

My issue is that the "data" event on upload isn't the upload progress but is the reading file from disk progress. I tried adding a "data" event to the form but that was the same result.

Basically how do I upload a file to my server and report the progress back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

[`request` uses `node-form-data`](https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms) to handle form uploads. As far as I know, [`node-form-data`](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data) doesn't provide any progress information, which means we need to find a clever workaround.

`node-form-data` uses [`combined-stream`](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data/blob/master/lib/form_data.js#L1), which looks likes implements a [correct pause/resume algorithm](https://github.com/felixge/node-combined-stream/blob/master/lib/combined_stream.js#L121-L137). This means that, even though `node-form-data` [doesn't support Node 0.10 streams](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data#todo), **it will still pause** its input stream (the file stream) if the request is too slow. In my mind, looking at the number of bytes sent by the file stream is a good enough approximation of the state of the POST request.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In practice i'm not sure this actually works. For example if I select a 50mb file to upload the input stream completes within a few seconds, meanwhile the actual upload if the file continues for 4-5 minutes on my connection. Maybe their is another library I can use for uploading files that does give me progress?

Comment: Which version of Node/Express are you using? [This gist](https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/7511372) works for me: the upload slows down because my connection is slow, and the rate of `console.log` messages slows down too.

Comment: I am running Node 10.18. I am not running Express, the server is just a normal PHP server. Maybe that is part of my problem? Because the PHP server doesn't stream the result AFAIK, it just waits for the whole thing to be ready then saves it.

Comment: This shoudln't interfere with the client-side code. Are you sure that you have network activity after Node says *File uploaded*?

Comment: Yep I am 100% positive. My upload is slow, even if I max out my connection it would take at least 3 minutes to upload a 50mb file. I get the 'File Uploaded' after 1-2 seconds in Node. I look at my network and see my upload is maxed for about another 3-4 mins, and I see on the server that the file appears and is logged just when my network activity stops.

Comment: It seems you should use an event emitter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) instead of `request`? Not sure that it does things differently, but it's worth a try.